# CSS blurred elements are not properly printed on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, css-filters

Elements with `-webki-filter: blur(5px)` are not properly printed on Chrome.

`-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact` doesn't help.

My Chrome version is 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit).

[JsBin](http://jsbin.com/gefaforale/edit?html,css)

Code:

```css
body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  background: gray;
}
.blurred {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="blurred"></div>
```